# listing and adding random generated numbers in java

Tags: java

I need my code to list the random generated numbers as well as add them together but I can't get anything to output.  Any suggestions welcome. Thanks!

```
    Random randomOutput = new Random();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    switch (game) {

        case 3:

            for(int gameLoops = 0; gameLoops > game; ++gameLoops){
                //System.out.println("gameloops is: " + gameLoops);
                int increaseBy = randomOutput.nextInt(9) + 1;
                System.out.println("The numbers randomly generated were: " + randomInt );
                sum += randomInt;
            }   
            break;

        case 4:
            for(int gameLoops = 0; gameLoops > game; ++gameLoops){
                int increaseBy = randomOutput.nextInt(9) + 1;
                System.out.println("The numbers randomly generated were: " + randomInt );
                sum += randomInt;
            }   
            break;

        case 5:
            for(int gameLoops = 0; gameLoops > game; ++gameLoops){
            int increaseBy = randomOutput.nextInt(9) + 1;
            System.out.println("The numbers randomly generated were: " + randomInt );
            sum += randomInt;
            }   
            break; 

    } // End Switch
```

Comment: What does " I can't get my switch to work" mean?

Comment: Please try to be concise, you have a very specific question, and yet you post a whole bunch of code.. which part of the code you are having issues.

Comment: Don't make everything `static`.

Comment: And you got a lot of code. I know, its painful; but please: take the time to really format it proper. You expect us to help you; then make our job easy. Do not expect us to spend our time trying to pull together the potentially existing useful code in this huge mess of code fragments.

Comment: This is my first time using this site.  I'm learning.

Comment: The `gameLoops > game` termination clause seems wrong, since you are incrementing in these for loops.

Comment: @Michael has a point. You are checking if `gameLoops > game`, which will **never** be true if `game` is a positive number.

Comment: Thank you both for your help.